# PDF is blue when it generated from image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am converting jpg to pdf using PIL library. Below is my code.

```
im = PIL.Image.open(filename)
PIL.Image.Image.save(im, newfilename, "PDF", resoultion = 200.0,quality = 100)
```

But output of pdf file is blur and also color of image is change.

Is there any class of PIL which use to avoid such things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You appear to have a typo, `resolution=200.0`

Comment: I try resolution=100.0 also.

Comment: The code you posted shows `resoultion` not `resolution`.

Answer (score 0):

I have success with this code, to convert a JPG to PDF:

```
from PIL import Image

inputfilename = "aaron.jpg"
outputfilename = "aaron.pdf"

im = Image.open(inputfilename)

dpi = None
if hasattr(im.info, "dpi"):
    dpi = im.info.dpi[0] # Assume horizontal DPI is same as vertical DPI.
if not dpi:
    dpi = 72 # Assume it's 72 if it's not specified in the JPG.

im.save(outputfilename, resolution=dpi, quality=100)
```

`im.save()` also works without the `resolution` and `quality` parameters, but I included them here because your example showed them.

Comment: Its working but problem is this the original image and pdf file both are looks different. colors are not same and also pdf is blur.

Comment: About the blurriness: That's image degradation caused by the lossy JPG compression.
Although we specify `quality=100`, the highest, it doesn't get any sharper. Can you use PNG pictures instead?

Comment: About the different size: That's because you don't take into account the DPI (dots per inch) of the JPG.
If you want to do that, use the `info.dpi` tuple from the loaded image. I have made the necessary changes to the code above.